# Serialize List content in a flat structure in jackson json (Java)

Tags: java, json, jackson

The class I need to Serialize:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class MyClass {

    @JsonProperty("CustomerId")
    private String customerId;

    @JsonProperty("Products")
    private List<ProductDetails> products;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

My ProductDetails.java class:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class ProductDetails {
    @JsonProperty("ProductId")
    private String productId;

    @JsonProperty("ProductName")
    private String productName;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

The default serialized output:

```
{
  "CustomerId" : "ewm0po",

  "Products" : [ {
       "ProductId" : "AAA",
       "ProductName" : "AAA Product"
     },  {
       "ProductId" : "AAA",
       "ProductName" : "AAA Product"
   }]
}
```

The output I'm trying to get:

```
{
  "CustomerId" : "ewm0po",
  "ProductId1" : "AAA",
  "ProductName1" : "AAA Product"
  "ProductId2" : "AAA",
  "ProductName2" : "AAA Product"
}
```

In other words, I am trying to skip the JSON brackets for the Products-list and suffix each of the ProductId and ProductName fields with a increasing integer.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Bad news - you're going to have write a custom serializer. Somewhat painful, but the only way to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Boris the spider pointed out. Writing a custom serializer was the solution. Not as painful as I expected :-)

Comment: Please share your implementation of the custom serializer.