# Serialize/Deserialize only the List/array content ,not array name

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am new to this Jackson serialization and deserialization. I have researched a lot of links for my issue ,didn't find any. So I am posting it here . Please help!

I have a three classes(entities) which i want to serialize and deserialize:

MyStackClass and MyService class are mapped by MyServiceMapping class.

```
public class MyStackClass implements Serializable, Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<MyserviceMapping> services;

}

public class MyserviceMapping implements Serializable,Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private MyStackClass myStackClass;

    @ManyToOne
    private MyService myService;

}

public class MyService implements Entity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int myServiceId;

    @OneToMany
    private  List<MyServiceMapping> myServices;

}
```

Now when i serialize MyStackClass: the json generated is like:

```
{
"id":1,
"services":[
     {"myService":
          {
             "myServiceId":27
          }
     },
     {"myService":
          {
             "myServiceId":3
          }
     }
]
}
```

But my client says that this is not upto the response guidleines. The json should not have extra myService tag inside the list,as it is already understood that this is a list of services . it should look like :

```
 {
    "id":1,
    "services":[
              {"myServiceId":27},
              {"myServiceId":3}
    ]
    }
```

I have tried some solutions but nothing worked.I do not want to go into manually setting the json ,I am looking at a clean jackson approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize a List content to a flat JSON object with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698499/how-to-serialize-a-list-content-to-a-flat-json-object-with-jackson)